# Meaning of exception in C# app: "Not a legal OleAut date"?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

Does anyone know what this means. Getting this in C# winforms applications:

> Not a legal OleAut date

Comment: Can you post the code that is causing this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It means that somewhere in the program is attempting to convert to or from an OLE Automation Date outside the valid range 1-January-4713 BC to 31-December-9999 AD. It might have slipped through because OLE Automation Dates are represented as a **double**.

Start by looking for any uses of the methods:

[DateTime.FromOADate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx)

[DateTime.ToOADate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate.aspx)

Answer (score 16):

An OADate is represented as a double value whose value is the number of days from midnight on 30 december 1899 (negative values representing earlier dates).

This exception is thrown when trying to convert a value that is outside the valid range of Ole Automation dates to/from a .NET DateTime value (methods DateTime.FromOADate and DateTime.ToOADate - which are also used implicitly for COM Interop).

I believe to be valid for conversion to an OADate the .NET DateTime value needs to be strictly greater than 01/01/0100.

To convert from OADate to a .NET DateTime value, the double value needs to be strictly greater than -657435 (= 01/01/0100) and strictly less than 2958466.0 (01/01/10000).

Answer (score 1):

It means you provided an invalid date somewhere, attempting to convert to or from an OLE Automation date outside the valid range 1-January-4713 BC to 31-December-9999 AD.  A possible cause is that it might have slipped through because OLE Automation Dates are represented as a double.

Comment: Isn't that a little too obvious an answer?

Comment: It's an obvious question, I don't know how one could be more helpful if the OP won't provide any details.

Comment: Agreed. We can't help more without further details like code.

Answer (score 0):

I've used:

```
try
{
    if (folderItem.ModifyDate.Year != 1899)
    {
        this.FileModifiedDate = folderItem.ModifyDate.ToShortDateString() + 
            " " +
            folderItem.ModifyDate.ToLongTimeString();
    }
}
//we need this because it throws an exception if it's an invalid date...
catch (ArgumentException) { }
```

to deal with the same problem I'm having. It throws the exception when we check the year in my case. Doing nothing on an invalid date is exactly the behavior I want, so this hack works.

Answer (score 0):

What I found was that a column with a large row_id '257381195' was attempting to be read by Excel as a Date.  What I ended up doing was altering that column's data to a string by preceding the row_id with a single quote.  This resolved my issue.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When trying to parse date from cell.

When converting string to double, the decimal separator was ignored because of my localization.

So the cell value `string:"123456,78"` was converted to `double:12345678` instead of `double:123456.78` (made-up example value used)

Here is my snippet that fixed the issue:

```cs
if (double.TryParse(
    s: cell.CellValue.InnerText,
    style: NumberStyles.Number,
    provider: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    result: out double oaDateValue))
{
  DateTime parsedDateTime = DateTime.FromOADate(oaDateValue);
  // DateTime was parsed successfully.
}
else
{
  // DateTime failed to parse.
}
```

The important part here is `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. This makes sure that if that cell has a decimal separator `.` or `,` it will be detected and parsed properly.

If you still get the error make sure that `cell.CellValue.InnerText` is an actual value and not a reference to `SharedStringTable`. If that's the case you can use this helper extension method that will help extract the value from `SharedStringTable`:

```cs
private static string GetCellValue(this Cell cell, SharedStringTable sharedStringTable)
{
    if (cell.DataType == null || !cell.DataType.HasValue)
    {
        return cell.CellValue != null
            ? cell.CellValue.InnerText
            : String.Empty;
    }
    else if (cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
    {
        return sharedStringTable
            .ElementAt(int.Parse(cell.CellValue.InnerText)).InnerText;
    }

    return cell.CellValue.InnerText;
}
```

Now you can use `cell.GetValue(sharedStringTable)` to get the actual string value.