# Conversion of Datetime of datatable in c#

Tags: c#, excel, datetime, datatable

I have a data table column which contains Date Value as `2014-09-10`.I am using EPPlus library to export this datatable column into Excel but is giving me error as..

```
Not a legal OleAut date.
```

I searched and got a solution over here [Stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310700/meaning-of-exception-in-c-sharp-app-not-a-legal-oleaut-date) and now i want to convert it into any of the Ole date methods like

```
public double ToOADate()
```

or

```
public static DateTime FromOADate(
double d
```

)

but not getting how to do it in my data table in c#.
Please help me..

Comment: is it a datetime column? Or a string column containing a date? I've had no problems with EPPlus exporting DataTable datetime columns

Comment: @MitchWheat It is a DateTime column..and this is my query `select DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') as date,time as time from table`

Comment: @MitchWheat R u helping me sir?

Comment: @MitchWheat Will You please update me on this ..Thanks..

Comment: Tried parsing? var oaDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2014-09-10", "yyyy-MM-dd", null).ToOADate();