# I get an eror in uploading excel db file to sql server in winforms C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, import-from-excel

I am trying to create an Excel data uploader to upload Excel files to SQL Server using Winforms in C#.

After `bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);` I get this error :

> Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.
>   The Connection for viewing your linked Microsoft Excel worksheet was lost.

I got information about regedit [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269495) and tried to follow it but still the same error:

```
class Pass
{
    static string _excelfilepath;

    public static string excelfilepath { get { return _excelfilepath; } set { _excelfilepath = value; } }

    public void importdatafromexcel()
    {
        //declare variables - edit these based on your particular situation
        string ssqltable = "tStudent";
        // make sure your sheet name is correct, here sheet name is sheet1, so you can change your sheet name if have different
        string myexceldataquery = "select idnum,fname,gname,mname,coacro,year,yrstat,sex,stat,telno,addr1,addr2,addr3,dbirth,mothname,fathname,civstat,religion,hssch from [masterlist$]";
        try
        {
            //create our connection strings
            string sexcelconnectionstring = @"provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=" + _excelfilepath +
            ";extended properties=" + "\"excel 8.0;hdr=yes;\"";
            string ssqlconnectionstring = @"Data Source=LYNDON-PC\LYNDON;Initial Catalog=trial;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=14323531";
            //execute a query to erase any previous data from our destination table
            string sclearsql = "delete from " + ssqltable;
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(ssqlconnectionstring);
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(sclearsql, sqlconn);
            sqlconn.Open();
            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlconn.Close();
            //series of commands to bulk copy data from the excel file into our sql table
            OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(sexcelconnectionstring);
            OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand(myexceldataquery, oledbconn);
            oledbconn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader dr = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader();
            SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ssqlconnectionstring);
            bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = ssqltable;
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
            }

            oledbconn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

What does the error mean and get the code to upload my Excel file to my table in my database in SQL Server...

Comment: Visit this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269495

Comment: Have you tried these steps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129744/multiple-step-ole-db-operation-generated-errors-check-each-ole-db-status-value

Comment: @Jenish Rabadiya, yup i tried that already and i linked it above..

Comment: @Selva TS, yes, I've been there, but still the same error..

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete hmm I didn't noticed that.

Comment: Do you have linked data in your worksheet?

Comment: @SelvaTS, what do you mean by linked data? I have information of students inside my excel file, with 19 column headers..

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete linked data means, having aggregate/concatenation  using some data in other sheet.

Comment: @SelvaTs, no, i don't think so...

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete Have you tried inserting the data into DataTable instead of BulkCopy?

Comment: @SelvaTS, no i have not tried it yet, I do not know how... Can you give a sample please?

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete From the above code, try something like this 

   OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(sexcelconnectionstring);
                OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand(myexceldataquery, oledbconn);
                oledbconn.Open();
                OleDbDataReader dr = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader();
                var dataTable = new DataTable();
                dataTable.Load(dr);
                oledbconn.Close();

Comment: @SelvaTS, i tried your code, but after dataTable.Load(dr);, it has the same error as before...

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/434atets%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) example there's no read action on the DataReader. Try to remove your `while(dr.Read())` and just WriteToServer(dr). (I think the bulk copy iterates over your reader anyhow).

Comment: @stefankmitph, now i get the error  = " Not a legal OleAut date. " what does this mean?

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310700/meaning-of-exception-in-c-sharp-app-not-a-legal-oleaut-date

Comment: @stefankmitph, in the last post of that link that you gave to me, Can you please explain how it works?

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete as it seems to me there is an error with the conversion of a date. is there a date field in your select / excel file?

Comment: @stefankmitph, yes there is.. and i can't edit it because, its a school property, they just gave me the excel file of the students list and information...

Comment: @Lyndon Broz Tonelete well, then i guess you have to convert the source data to fit the destination table.

Comment: @stefankmitph, how can i do that sir?

Comment: @Lyndon Broz Tonelete that's a completely different question. i'd go for a solution like this: use [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) to get values from oledb connection and then either map the data to mssql manually or use a library like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper). then insert the sql data. Dapper and AutoMapper both are available through NuGet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use

```
bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
```

instead of using

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why this would help?

Comment: Hi. Method WriteToServer calls method Read until it returns false, the operation is aborted, or an error occurs. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/434atets(v=vs.110).aspx